# PLMXML with Python?

Tags: python

Does anyone have an idea on how to deal with PLMXML and python? I have been searching but didnt find too much. If anyone could give me a direction I would appreciate.

I have a huge PLMXML, but I edited to show the information that I want to get from it. 
I want to get the values: **"RED: [1, 0, 0]", "GREEN: [0, 1, 0]" and "BLUE:[0, 0 , 1]"**.
Its something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <PLMXML xmlns="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema" schemaVersion="6.1" author="XXXXXXXXXXX" time="00:00:00.000+00:00" date="0000-00-00+00:00" name="000000000000">
      <ProductDef id="000">
        <InstanceGraph Ref="000 0000 000000 000000 00000 000000" name="instancegraphname" id="instancegraphid">
          </ProductInstance>
          <ProductRevisionView type="productrevisionviewtype" name="productrevisionname" id="productrevisionid" />
          <ProductInstance Ref="priductinstanceref" id="productinstanceid" name="productinstancename">
            <UserData type="userdatatype" id="userdataid">
              <UserValue title="userdataValueTitle" value="userdatavalue" id="userdataid" />
              <UserValue title="1" value="RED: [1, 0, 0]" id="id_red" />
              <UserValue title="2" value="GREEN: [0, 1, 0]" id="id_green" />
              <UserValue title="3" value="BLUE:[0, 0 , 1]" id="id_blue" />
            </UserData>
          </ProductInstance>
          </ProductRevisionView>
        </InstanceGraph>
      </ProductDef>
    </PLMXML>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) package to parse the file (Assuming it's valid XML, which is not true of the example in the question).

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> ET.parse('pl.xml')
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x7f9bfab8b700>
>>> tree = ET.parse('pl.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> for elem in root.iter('{http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema}UserValue'):print(elem.attrib['value'])
... 
userdatavalue
RED: [1, 0, 0]
GREEN: [0, 1, 0]
BLUE:[0, 0 , 1]
```

For serious XML work, consider installing and using the [lxml](https://lxml.de) package.

Comment: JFYI Beautiful Soup wraps around XML and provides a slightly cleaner interface if interested.. https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=xml#parsing-xml